# UIScrollView at 3x zoom with UIView overlay

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, logic

I have a UIScrollView containing a large image of size 3354 x 2082. I have the UIScrollView zoomed out to display the entire image. I am adding red circles like this:

```
CGRect positionFrame = CGRectMake(500,500,5,5);
RedCircle * circleView = [[RedCircle alloc] initWithFrame:positionFrame];
[self.scrollView addSubview:circleView];
```

Problem - The red circle does not have the same position in zoom out (newZoomScale = 0.305307f;) and full zoom (newZoomScale = 3.0f;).

This is more of a logical question than syntax. Any genius out there who can help?

EDIT: Posting entire code:

```
@interface MainMap ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

- (void)centerScrollViewContents;
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
@end

@implementation MainMap
@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Set up the image we want to scroll & zoom and add it to the scroll view
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"worldMap.jpg"];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

// Tell the scroll view the size of the contents
self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
//self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewTwoFingerTapped:)];
twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
twoFingerTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Set up the minimum & maximum zoom scales
CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0f;
self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

[self centerScrollViewContents];


CGRect positionFrame = CGRectMake(500,500,5,5);
RedCircle * circleView = [[RedCircle alloc] initWithFrame:positionFrame];
[self.scrollView addSubview:circleView];
}


- (void)centerScrollViewContents{
CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
// Get the location within the image view where we tapped
CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

// Get a zoom scale that's zoomed in slightly, capped at the maximum zoom scale specified by the scroll view
CGFloat newZoomScale = 0.0f;
if(self.scrollView.zoomScale == 3.0f)
{
    newZoomScale = 0.305307f;
} else
{
    newZoomScale = 3.0f;
}

newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale);

// Figure out the rect we want to zoom to, then zoom to it
CGSize scrollViewSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;

CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

[self.scrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];


float scale = self.scrollView.zoomScale;
CGRect positionFrame = CGRectMake(500 * scale, 500 * scale ,50,50);
RedCircle * circleView = [[RedCircle alloc] initWithFrame:positionFrame];
[self.scrollView addSubview:circleView];
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
// Return the view that we want to zoom
return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
// The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
[self centerScrollViewContents];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:circleView];
```

I should have

```
[self.imageView addSubview:circleView];
```

That solved all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use the zoomScale property of the UIScrollView.

```
float scale = self.scrollView.zoomScale;
CGRect positionFrame = CGRectMake(500 * scale, 500 * scale ,5,5);
```

Adjust position in `scrollViewDidZoom:` delegate method.

Comment: Not working. I posted all the code for your reference. I did add your code in the delegate method as well but no joy.

Comment: The red circle is not in view after the double tap.

Comment: @sangony, it looks like you're just calling `centerScrollViewContents` in `scrollViewDidZoom` and there's no code in there to readjust the circles.

Comment: I hear you, understand no but i hear you. I bypassed the centerScrollViewContents but the problem still persists. Any suggestions on what I can do?